# How can I batch convert using chm2pdf on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, file-conversion

I am unsure of what part of my command is improper, but I am given no error and only a usage page when entering the following:

```
/usr/bin/chm2pdf --book *.chm *.pdf
```

and

```
/usr/bin/chm2pdf --book *.chm [*.pdf]
```

More to the point, I have a directory 100+ .chm files I was tasked with converting, and the usage for batch converting was practically nonexistent in any of the documentation, so a wildcard may not be the way to go, evidently.

Here is the message I am provided:

```
#/usr/bin/chm2pdf --book *.chm [*.pdf]
Usage:
        /usr/bin/chm2pdf [options] input_filename [output_filename]

Options:
...
```

My question, more specifically, refers to batch conversion, as I used the examples above to convert single .chm files properly, and in the description of the utility, batch conversion is evidently a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your syntax is right, but you'll need to iterate through the items for a batch job.

If they're all in the same folder, something as simple as this script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.chm"`; do
    /usr/bin/chm2pdf --book ${i} `echo ${i} | sed 's/.chm/.pdf/'`
done
```

That should be closer to what you need.

To explain it:

1) You're listing all matching files to the type *.chm at a max depth of 1 folder (the folder you're in).
2) For each of those, run `/usr/bin/chm2pdf` with `${i}` being the individual item's name.  Then replacing the file name for the out-file from "whatever.chm" to "whatever.pdf".
3) Then done.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's working; the titles of the .chm files seem to be throwing it off, but other than that, seems to be working.

Comment: What do you mean?  Something we can adjust to help you out more?

Comment: I just reordered the first line to for i in `find . -maxdepth 1  "*.chm" -type f -name`; do (to resolve a seemingly innocuous warning) then I changed my original line from --book to --webpage. Between all that it seems to be working fine now. Thanks again.